# Why I am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unobtrusive' of undefined (Repeated 2 times)

Tags: jquery, reference

Here is the screenshot of references my page is adding. I am using MVC 4 Razor.

**EDIT:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.20/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="/MaxVSM/css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var ApplicationRoot = '/MaxVSM';
    if (!window.jQuery) {
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/MaxVSM/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"><\/script>');
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/MaxVSM/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js"><\/script>')
    } else {
        if (!window.jQuery.ui)
            document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/MaxVSM/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js"><\/script>')
    }
</script>

<link href="/MaxVSM/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/MaxVSM/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/MaxVSM/css/Common.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="/MaxVSM/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/MaxVSM/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/MaxVSM/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="/MaxVSM/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script>
<script src="/MaxVSM/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.debug.js"></script>

<script src="/MaxVSM/Scripts/json2.js"></script>
<script src="/MaxVSM/Scripts/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.js"></script>
<script src="/MaxVSM/Js/Common.js"></script>
<script src="/MaxVSM/Js/CustomDateControl.js"></script>
```

`if (!window.jQuery)`:
Actually I am giving the reference of jQuery through Google APIs. If it is not found on the page it will refer to local path for jQuery.

Comment: Please no raw screenshot only, copy paste the code is a lot easier to read for us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>You need to check your library order. I think JQuery first here will help :)</strike>

Edit, add this before :

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That i know i have to check the order but what is correct order'

Comment: @GauravSharma jquery first, jquery plugins after

Comment: screenshot already contains jquery first and plugins after....

Comment: @GauravSharma aaaah didn't see....... please provide code, not screenshot. even better if you can provide a jsfiddle. Also i dont understand your if(window.jQuery) [...] why rewriting js include?

Comment: @GauravSharma look at the duplicated link upthere. You missed the [Validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)