# Reactjs + ASP MVC Unobtrusive Validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive

I have next code

```
componentDidMount() {
    super.componentDidMount();
    let jobj = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(jobj);
}
```

after run this, i get error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unobtrusive' of undefined**

How can i make import ASP MVC unobtrusive and jquery validation?

Answer (score 3):

From the error, it looks like $.validator is not attached yet.

Check whether you missed out the jquery.validate.min.js before rendering your React component (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185306/why-i-am-getting-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-unobtrusive-of-undef)).

On using ASP.NET MVC and unobstrusive, this is a question which I have been researching for the past few days, too. Let me share some of my initial thoughts on this:

**Validation works out of the box with React**

Judging by how the unobstrusive validation works, as long as you enhance your JSX or TSX(Typescript v1.6+) or react script with the data-val-* attributes, the unobstrusive plugin will do the magic for you already.

```
var TextInputComponent = React.createClass({
    render() {        
    return (
        <div>
            <input data-val="true" data-val-required="error msg" name="Test" type="text" />
            <span className="text-danger"  data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Test"></span>
        </div>
    );
}
});
```

**Problem space**

The problems is we (ASP.NET MVC devs) are used to having Razor generate all the attributes for us via @Html.TextFor(...) method (and its variants for other input types). Now we need to to **pass** these attributes to ReactJS component so that they know how a particular field is supposed to be validated.

I am planning to test whether the following works:

1. Use the HtmlHelper's GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes method to get all the attributes related to ViewModel metadata. Something like this Extension method:

   ```
   public static IDictionary<string, object> UnobtrusiveValidationAttributesFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> propertyExpression)
   {
       var propertyName = html.NameFor(propertyExpression).ToString();
       var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(propertyExpression, html.ViewData);
       var attributes = html.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(propertyName, metadata);
       return attributes;
   }
   ```
2. Output this method into JSON or Javascript Object and assign it to a Javascript variable (either global or scoped to ReactDOM.render method)
3. Use JSX spread feature to include the variable from (2) as props. (see [here](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html))

In short, to have a complete form with ASP.NET validation, we need to tell ReactJS components all the necessary data-val-* info.

Comment: thanks for response, i solved problem like this
window.$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(jobj); instead $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(jobj);

Comment: what came about from your findings, @ronnypm?